# Detect in Symfony2 TypeExtension if a type is a prototype root

Tags: forms, symfony, prototype

### Form type extension problem

I'm writing a FormExtension that apply to all form type (experimenting with angularjs... another story :), but I need to detect at *build* time if a FormType is used as prototype root.

```
class MyFormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (true /* === $iAmPrototypeRoot*/) {
            $builder->setAttribute('i_need', 'magic');
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to set some attributes that I need later, but setAttribute is (or seems to be) available only at build time.

### So far...

I've checked the source code for `CollectionType` and found this:

```
class CollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['allow_add'] && $options['prototype']) {
            $prototype = $builder->create($options['prototype_name'], $options['type'], array_replace(array(
                'label' => $options['prototype_name'].'label__',
            ), $options['options']));
            $builder->setAttribute('prototype', $prototype->getForm());
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

So I know that I can override this template and add a "fake" option `is_prototype` to the options, but this is a bit hackish since I'm overriding (not extending) the default `CollectionType`. Example:

```
class CollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['allow_add'] && $options['prototype']) {
            $prototype = $builder->create($options['prototype_name'], $options['type'], array_replace(array(
                'label' => $options['prototype_name'].'label__',
            ), $options['options'], array(
                'is_prototype' => true
            )));
            $builder->setAttribute('prototype', $prototype->getForm());
        }

        // [...]
    }
}
```

### Which solution?

Up 'til now, the best solution I see is to add the 'is_prototype' to the [collection option `option`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#options) (no pun :); but this should persist if the user override the option (maybe a Normalizer?)

Answer (score 0):

After having struggled for a while I found the solution and it is easy (if you know it):

```
private function isPrototypeRoot($options)
{
    return $options['block_name'] === 'entry';
}
```

Hope this will save some headache.

## TL;DR

[`block_name`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#block-name) is the option that allow you to override the block name used to render the form type. By digging into `CollectionType` I found this:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $optionsNormalizer = function (Options $options, $value) {
        $value['block_name'] = 'entry';

        return $value;
    };
    // [...]
    $resolver->setNormalizers(array(
        'options' => $optionsNormalizer,
    ));
}
```

Normalization happens right after option resolution (even lazy resolution), and once executed the options are set immutable. Since `block_name` is forced to be equal to `entry`, and this is not found anywhere into symfony sources, I can safely assume that is a "prototype"